# How to center a div with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

how can i center a div that is inside `span7` so that `span7` and `span5` both will display in same line.I am using bootstrap 2.3.2

this is my code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/aCD89/1/)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
                <!-- 1st Column -->
    <div class="span7">
         <div id="imagediv" style="position: relative;">
             <img src="" style="z-index: 0;" >
         </div>           
    </div>
                <!-- END 1st Column -->


                <!-- 2nd Column -->

    <div class="span5">
        <div>
            <p class="well" style="min-height: 440px; word-wrap: break-word;"> Profile Info </p>
        </div>   
    </div>

          <!-- End 2nd Column -->
</div>
```

How can i make `imagediv` into center of `span7`

Comment: what about `<div class="span7 text-center">` or do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: i tried this `text-center` is not working [link](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/aCD89/1/)

Comment: what browser do you use? chrome, firefox, opera, ie? and what version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-center` class to the div

```
<div class="span7 text-center">
     <div id="imagediv" style="position: relative;">
         <img src="http://s25.postimg.org/scg5jg3rf/profile.jpg" style="z-index: 0;" />
     </div>           
</div>
```

working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aCD89/3/

screenshot output:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div id="imagediv" class="text-center" style="position: relative;">
             <img src="" style="z-index: 0;" >
         </div>
```

add class `text-center`

Comment: He wants to center the div inside the div with class span7. this centers the content of the div inside the div with class span7.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS property as margin : 0 auto; to #imagediv